# Pythonでdictから存在しない可能性があるキーの削除

Tags: python

Pythonでdictからキーを削除するにはdelを使用しますが、削除しようとしたキーが存在しない場合にKeyErrorが発生してしまいます。

```
>>> a = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> del a["c"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

これを回避するためには以下の様に事前にキーが存在するかチェックする必要があるのですが、

```
>>> a = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> if "c" in a:
...     del a["c"]
... 
>>>
```

存在しない可能性があるキーを削除するのに、もっと簡単に書く方法はありますか？

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) を使いましょう

```
a = dict(a=1, b=2)
a.pop('c', None) # None
print a          # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
a.pop('a', None) # 1
print a          # {'b': 2}
```

> If `key` is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return `default`. If `default` is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a KeyError is raised.

`pop(key[, default])` は辞書からキーを削除して、要素の値、あるいは `default` を返します。含まれてないキーを `pop` する時に、2番目の引数 `default` を渡さないと、`KeyError` が起きます。上記の例のような `None` で指定すれば良いです。